# Impliment parent class's hover css to its child tag hover css

Tags: html, css

In my scenario, i want to call css of parent class's child tag hovering css on hovering of parent css.

here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/becpjjdw/)

I want to call the css of `.videos-holder figure figcaption:hover` on hover of `.videos-holder figure:hover`

Is it possible to do this without adding new IDs and Classes? Btw, my main purpose is to change color of `<figcaptio>` on hovering on `<figure>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.videos-holder figure  figcaption:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    filter: grayscale(0%);
     -webkit-transition: .2s; /* Safari */
    transition: .2s;
}
```

**`Replace to`**

```
.videos-holder figure:hover  figcaption{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
    filter: grayscale(0%);
     -webkit-transition: .2s; /* Safari */
    transition: .2s;
}
```